# SSIS: Error with special characters in the column when using 64 bit ANSI MySQL odbc driver

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Source table in MySQL has a column of type 'text'. What is the best datatype that I can have in the destination table in SQL Server.

I have used 'ntext', 'nvarchar(max)', and 'varchar(max)'. All of them threw an error cannot convert between Unicode and Non-Unicode string data-types.

Note: I am using 64 bit ODBC ANSI driver

**Update:** The field has some special characters resulting in the error. This is happening only with ANSI driver. I'm researching on any work arounds; something like casting. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For Unicode you'll use `NVARCHAR`, non-Unicode you'll use `VARCHAR` assuming you expect variable length data. `NTEXT` won't be supported in future versions of SQL Server. Show your code and perhaps we can catch the error. [**Here is a conversion chart**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2203/mysql-to-sql-server-data-type-comparisons/)

Comment: When I used 32 bit Unicode ODBC driver, text to nvarchar(max) and text to ntext worked perfectly fine. I am having trouble ever since I started using 64 bit ODBC ANSI driver.

Comment: very odd Karthik. Nothing else has changed?

Comment: Yeah strange !! and Nope. Nothing else changed.

Comment: @scsimon .. the field has some special characters resulting in the error. This happens only with ANSI driver. I'm researching on a work around something like casting.